# Should a [term-limits] tag be created, or should that tag be made a synonym of [election-requirements]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There are 29 questions that refer to "term limits" or "term limit"; some as a limitation on re-election.

- [20 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22term+limits%22+is%3Aq) `"term limits" is:q`
- [9 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22term+limit%22+-%22term+limits%22+is%3Aq) `"term limit" -"term limits" is:q`

Due to the number of questions referring to "term limits", a [term-limits](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/term-limits) tag could be useful. However, "term limits" are a *negative* requirement "to stand for election"; therefore, it may be reasonable to make that tag a synonym of [election-requirements](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election-requirements).

[election-requirements](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election-requirements) excerpt:

> Requirements to stand for election. These may include a minimum age, citizenship, residency, or other criteria.

Should a [term-limits](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/term-limits) tag be created?

Should that tag be made a synonym of [election-requirements](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election-requirements)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When deciding whether a new tag should be added, there are generally four considerations.

#### 1: Is it useful?

Can one know a lot about term limits, but not know a lot about election requirements? I'd say the answer to this is probably yes, as term limits are a lot more well known than many other election requirements.
It's probably worth doing an analysis of how many questions would use the tag before adding it, and I might add one once I get some more time.

#### 2: is it competing for space with other tags?

Out of the 29 questions you linked, only 1 of those has 5 tags. That one doesn't really need the term limits tag.

#### 3: is it on topic, and is it a duplicate?

As I mentioned earlier, I don't think it's a duplicate of [election-requirements](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election-requirements), and it's most definitely on topic. Possibly a duplicate of [presidential-term](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presidential-term), but since it applies to all term limits, not just those of presidents, I think it should be fine.

So, **I think that the tag should be added.**

Comment: I agree - add it, but it's not a very clear or discoverable synonym, and that's not necessary.

Answer (score -2):

It's not a synonym of "election requirements" though.  There is no reason for someone looking through the term-limits tag to be presented with a questions about all other types of election requirements.